# How to delete Angular Material icons hosted offline?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have hosted Angular material icons offline. Currently, I am using some of the icons. Is there any way I can remove unused icons along with its CSS classes as it consumes lot of space?

Comment: How many space they consumes ? Do you know ?

Comment: maybe you can remove them via node_moduls ... but why is it so needed?

Comment: Cannot delete via node_modules,I have hosted https://github.com/google/material-design-icons offline.

Answer (score 0):

**To delete icons:**

You need to convert `.woff2` file to `.ttf` you can use this link to do that: [Font Converter](https://onlinefontconverter.com/). Then you can use some font editor: [Font Editor](https://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator) to delete icons you no need, and back again convert to `.woff2`. Or check are editor works with `.woff2` files.

**How to host:**

Download `.woff2` file from : https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v48/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2

Copy paste to your styles.css file:

```css
/* fallback */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  // src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v48/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');
  src: url(Path to .woff2 file) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: I have hosted it offline (locally). I am not downloading it from internet. I have the entire icon set along with its CSS from which I use only few of them.

Comment: Yeah i changing answear. XD

Comment: I have woff2, woff, eot and ttf files in iconfont folder

Comment: Yes and i think only `.woff2` you need to display icons.

Comment: or no ? just download https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v48/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2 those are icons you will need i think.

Comment: @fvales Edited and explained how to host files.

Comment: Yes, I have that. I have iconfont folder (Which contains woff, woff2, eot and ttf files), sprites folder (which contains png and svg folder), and set of images folder (Which has loads of png images). What I have done is, I deleted the set of images folder and sprites folder... and it still works. The  file size of woff file is in some kilo bytes that hardly matters... Whatever I am doing, is it correct?

Comment: Yeah this folder you had it's setup for really old browsers and because of Angular is new and will not go on old browsers i think he might need just `.woff2` file and thats it.

Comment: There might be possibility that `.woff2` files have their own possibility to download some files by url but i dont think so.